# PowerMock and Mockito casue UnfinishedVerificationException

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I'm using PowerMock and Mockito together. I have the following includes:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;
```

This at the top of my testing class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

Then I have a test with the following checks:

```
verifyNew(ExternalNode.class, atLeastOnce());
verify(nodeResolutor).comm();
```

But I get a UnfinishedVerificationException exception. However if I invert the two instructions everything is working fine. How is it possible?

Here is the exception stacktrace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocation.MockitoNewInvocationControl.verify(MockitoNewInvocationControl.java:95)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.

    at com.janny.MyTest.verifyResults(MyTest.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

What can be the problem? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

`verifyNew` returns [a ConstructorArgumentsVerification object](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.6.0/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/verification/ConstructorArgumentsVerification.html) that PowerMock [wants you to call](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#How_to_verify_construction_of_new_objects).

```
verifyNew(ExternalNode.class, atLeastOnce()).withNoArguments();
    /* or */
verifyNew(ExternalNode.class, atLeastOnce()).withArguments("foo", "bar");
```

The inverse order works only because PowerMock can only detect that your syntax is wrong the next time you interact with PowerMock, Mockito, or a mock. When your `verifyNew` comes first, PowerMock gets called in the subsequent `verify` and figures out something's wrong. This code would also produce the same exception:

```
verify(nodeResolutor).comm();
verifyNew(ExternalNode.class, atLeastOnce()); /*BAD: no withNoArguments here*/
verify(nodeResolutor).anyOtherMethod();
```

Catching unfinished verification and stubbing like these is part of the reason that it makes sense to call [`Mockito.validateMockitoUsage()`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#validateMockitoUsage()) in an `@After` method (or `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class`, which does the same thing outside of PowerMock), but I don't know if it would catch the PowerMock problem here.